# Google Drive Picker - select folders to upload

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I have my picker code as follows:

```
var mimetypes = "application/vnd.ms-excel," +
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet," +
                        "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet," +
                        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint," +
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation," +
                        "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation," +
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document," +
                        "application/msword," +
                        "application/vnd.google-apps.document," +
                        "application/pdf,"+
                        "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
          var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
          view.setMimeTypes(mimetypes);

         var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView()
          .setIncludeFolders(true) 
          .setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder')
          .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

       var folderView = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.FODLERS);
       folderView.setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
              .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MINE_ONLY)
              .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
              .setAppId(appId)
              .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
              .addView(view)
              .addView(docsView)
              .addView(folderView)
              .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
              .setSelectableMimeTypes(mimetypes)
              .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
              .setCallback(pickerCallback)
              .build();
           picker.setVisible(true);
```

I have added the view to enable "**setSelectFolderEnabled**"  **but still after selecting the folder form Picker View, the "Select" button in the bottom remains disabled**. I need the folder Id in callback for further processing. But I am unable to figure out **how to enable the button even if a folder is selected.**

***Does Google Picker API only allow to select files saved in Google Drive ??***

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just changed my code to this and it works :

```
 var docsView = new google.picker.DocsView().
                                 setIncludeFolders(true).
                                 setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
              .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MINE_ONLY)
              .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
              .setAppId(appId)
              .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
              .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
              .addView(docsView)
              .setCallback(pickerCallback)
              .build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `google.picker.​ViewId.FOLDERS` viewId in the `addView`. I think you can't select folders due to it not being set in the `PickerView.Builder`. More information about the View Descriptions can be found on the [Showing Different Views](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews) of the Picker API documentation.

After that, determine if you have write scopes for you to upload files to Drive.

Comment: As per your suggestion I added the "FOLDERS" view but still after selecting folder in the view , the "Select" button remains disabled. I have edited my question with the updated codes