# Why is select button in App Maker Drive Picker not enabled?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Drive Picker widget in Google App Maker that pops up and lets me select a folder.  However, the Select button is greyed out.

I have entries for selectedDocUrl, selectedDocName, and onDocumentSelect, but I cannot get the button to be clickable.  My views is set to FOLDERS and my security is set to run as the user's account.  I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436836/google-drive-picker-select-folders-to-upload) but since I am using App Maker I don't see how to apply it.

Any idea how to enable this button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has confirmed they have fixed the problem and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your link the issue must be that we don't allow selecting folders even though we allow selecting the folders view. Looks like an App Maker bug that we'll have to fix, I can't think of any work around short of implementing your own picker. Edit: I've filed a bug within Google to track this.